# Adding the sum of array elements and storing them into another array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, addition, store

The fragment of code which I'm about to post is from a program which is supposed to ask the user a series of multiple choice questions. The program will then keep score for each question and have a total which will be stored in another array. I will have multiple players playing this, so that's why i will need 2 arrays.

Here is what i have:

```
//Asks questions and stores score in array
public static int [] questions ()
{
    userinput=""; //input will be stored in here
    int total[]= new int[100];
    int score[]=new int[5];
    for(int i=0; i < ps.length; i++)
    {
        userinput=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(que[i]); //Outputs a question stored in   another array in another method.
        if (response.equals(ans[i])) //this compares the user input to the correct answer of the question, which is in another method.
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You selected " + " " + ans[i] + " You were correct, 1 point!");
            score[i]=1;
            total[i]=total[i]+score[i];
        }
        else if(!response.equals(ans[i])) // If the answer isn't correct
        {
            score[i]=0; // I want to assign 0 for the question
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You're wrong!, The correct answer was "+ans[i]);
        }
    } // close loop
    return total; // return's this to another method which will do all of the other work
}
```

I seem to be having the problem here:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You selected " + " " + ans[i] + " You were correct, 1 point!");
score[i]=1;
total[i]=total[i]+score[i];
```

I want to add 1 to each element in score[] if the answer is correct. Then i want to accumulate the total of score[] and store that in each element of total[]. I return total to another method which stores it in an array.

Comment: Your suspicious code is the same as `totalscore[i]++`. Besides, `totalscore` has 100 elems, whereas `score` has 15 elems. Why?

Comment: Sorry it was a copy and paste error. The only 2 arrays i'm working with are score[] and total[].

Comment: If you see any array's other than "total[]" or "score[]" ignore them!

Comment: This still leaves my question unanswered, I guess...

Comment: Total[] has the value 100 because i will have multiple players, playing this. I just gave it a value which will be more than enough.

Comment: Please mind formatting your code. You can do this online at http://www.prettyprinter.de/module.php?name=PrettyPrinter if you have no IDE in front of you :)

Comment: Score[] is 5, because i will have 5 questions and 5 possible answers

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so it seems you need to pass ordinal of current user in your method, so it can calculate correct position inside `total` array. Since it seems you want to aggregate total scores across multiple question/answer sessions, you need to pass `total` from outside:

```
public static void questions(int userOrdinal, int[] total) {
    final int questionsPerUser = 5;

    userinput = ""; //input will be stored in here
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsPerUser; i++) {
        userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(que[i]); //Outputs a question stored in   another array in another method.
        if (response.equals(ans[i])) //this compares the user input to the correct answer of the question, which is in another method.
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You selected " + " " + ans[i] + " You were correct, 1 point!");
            total[userOrdinal * questionsPerUser + i] = 1;
        } else if (!response.equals(ans[i])) // If the answer isn't correct
        {
            total[userOrdinal * questionsPerUser + i] = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're wrong!, The correct answer was " + ans[i]);
        }
    } // close loop
}
```

Sorry, I still can't get why you need `score` array, since your initial code is the same as `total[i]++` and you never read contents of `score`, only write to it.